# Is it possible to stretch video in video.js flash player?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, flash, video.js

I'm using [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) (v 4.3.0) with flash player on internet explorer.
How can i stretch the video to container area like in this example http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_autofitexample.html?

I've tried some modification on video.dev.js file to add `<PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="exactfit">` on generated flash object. And also i've changed the wmode from opaque to transparent like in the example page code. Modified video.js generates the flash player as below and still not stretching.

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" class="vjs-tech" name="video_1_flash_api" id="video_1_flash_api" data="video-js.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="display: block;">
    <param value="video-js.swf" name="movie">
    <param value="readyFunction=videojs.Flash.onReady&amp;eventProxyFunction=videojs.Flash.onEvent&amp;errorEventProxyFunction=videojs.Flash.onError&amp;autoplay=true&amp;preload=auto&amp;loop=undefined&amp;muted=undefined&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fh5mp%2F_html%2F1.html&amp;" name="flashvars">
    <param value="exactfit" name="scale">
    <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
    <param value="all" name="allowNetworking">
    <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
</object>
```